# Python create list based on letter index of existing list

Tags: python, text, orientation, skew, text-rotation

So I am trying to work on a script which allows me to take a text file,
rotate the layout 90 degrees and keep all the letters in the correct orientation (as opposed to having the letters turn sideways)

Right so If I have a list like so:

```
x = ['the','boy','ate','jam','pie']
```

How can I create a list based off of the index position of the letters within each list item.

```
letters[0] = t,b,a,j,p
letters[1] = h,o,t,a,i
letters[2] = e,y,e,m,e

x = ['tbajp','hotai','eyeme']
```

Where I am at:

```
new_list = []

x = ["the","boy","ate","jam","pie"]

y = len(x)

t = 0
while y > 0:

  z = len(x[0])
  c = 0

  while z > 0:
    print(x[t][c])
    z -= 1
    c += 1

  y -= 1
  t += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Shortest method using `list(zip(*x))`:

```
x = ['the','boy','ate','jam','pie']
rotate_list = [''.join(i) for i in list(zip(*x))]
print(rotate_list)
```

Output:

```
['tbajp', 'hotai', 'eyeme']
```

**Edit:**

You can reverse the `rotate_list` by using:

```
reversed_strings = [''.join(i)[::-1] for i in list(zip(*x))]
```

Output:

```
['pjabt', 'iatoh', 'emeye']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `zip` function:

```
x = ['the','boy','ate','jam','pie']
list(zip(*x))
[('t', 'b', 'a', 'j', 'p'), ('h', 'o', 't', 'a', 'i'), ('e', 'y', 'e', 'm', 'e')]
```

Note: if the strings are not all of equal length you may want to use `itertools.zip_longest` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
def rotate(input_list: list) -> list:
    print(f"Input List is: {input_list}")
    output_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(input_list)):
        output_string = ""
        for string in input_list:
            if i < len(string):
                output_string += string[i]

        if output_string:
            output_list.append(output_string)

    print(f"Output List is: {output_list}")
    return output_list


rotate(['the', 'boy', 'ate', 'jam', 'pie'])
```

As you can see in the above code,

- we are iterating over the `input_list` and fetch character at index i from each string.
- As all strings may not be of the same length we need to make sure we are not trying to fetch the index which is not present within the string.
- At the end, we check if the `output_string` is generated, and we append it to the output list.

Output:

```
#python3 test5.py
Input List is: ['the', 'boy', 'ate', 'jam', 'pie']
Output List is: ['tbajp', 'hotai', 'eyeme']
```